# Get visual output over ssh

Tags: server, ssh, putty, solr

I have a remote ubuntu 14 installation and I am running `apache solar` and `apache nutch` on it. At the moment I am connecting over windows 7, with putty to my server.
Apache Solr has a if you open on the server the browser to `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/` a visual interface, to create queries and analyse data.

I would like to access this interface over ssh too? Is there sth like a visual ssh program?

I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: forward the port - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding use the ip address of the server and go ahead and bind it locally. `ssh -L 8938:your_server_ip:8983 your_server_ip` then connect with "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/" I your browser.

Answer (score -3):

You can connect to the server using the `ssh -X username@servername` option and then lunch `firefox http://localhost:8983/solr/admin`

Comment: No you can not do that as firefox will run LOCALLY. It is bizarre behavior over ssh and firefox. If you want to do this sort of thing, you use something like - https://calomel.org/firefox_ssh_proxy.html . Try it yourself, run firefox as you say and look at the output of `ps aux | grep firefox` local and on the server.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/3515/how-do-i-launch-a-remote-firefox-window-via-ssh

Comment: I've just tried on a remote centos server and it works fine. I get 2 different versions of firefox running. The centos version is older than the one in 14.04.

Comment: You "can" forward firefox over ssh with -X and centos may well be configured different then Ubuntu. It will not work on Ubuntu as it does on your end with a centos/ubuntu mix as Ubuntu != Centos (see the second link I gave you). Even if you do a `-no-remote` option in Firefox, IMO, there is no real need to tunnel firefox over X, just port forward as in the answers I linked. The connection will be faster and use less bandwidth, more so with a caching proxy on the remote.