# Error "libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found" & "libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast" in Ubuntu 18.04. Ubuntu or XQuartz issue?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, xorg, x11-forwarding

When I `ssh -X` into my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop from my Mac OSX computer, I am able to get in. However, when I try to run firefox or rstudio, I get

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

followed by

```
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (8 8 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 8 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8)
QQuickWidget: Failed to make context current
QQuickWidget::resizeEvent() no OpenGL context
QQuickWidget: Failed to make context current
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (8 8 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 8 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8)
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
Could not link shader program:
```

I know that there are issues with XQuartz in Mac (I am on Catalina), but are these issues on my Ubuntu Desktop or from Mac? I have the Nvidia 430 driver, I installed them again but the above error keeps appearing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I get the error message in your first box when starting paraview plus omitted specifics. I have not found a fix for my case to offer, but I would suggest to take a look at this other answer https://askubuntu.com/a/566522/446253 for clues

Comment: I have the opposite problem: the error pops up on my local computer, while the paraview program starts in full glory when I log in via `ssh -YC ...`. So this appears to depend on local configurations, not on the program itself. Added to offer another clue.

Comment: I figured it out, it was because XQuartz doesnt have support for the nvidia driver. When you tunnel in, it will show that the default set of drivers is actually not my nvidia driver

Comment: What do you mean by "tunnel in"? How did you solved the issue?

Comment: Try taking a look at this related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3515/how-do-i-launch-a-remote-firefox-window-via-ssh

Answer (score 6):

I got same error when using gnuplot. The reset of environment variable works for me:

```
$ export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
```

The solution comes from: https://psycomp.utsc.utoronto.ca/support/index.php/2021/10/14/libgl-error-when-using-ssh-x-forwarding-with-macos/