# Chrome window missing menu bar, tabs, etc when launched via SSH

Tags: ssh, google-chrome

When I SSH to a remote box

```
$ ssh -X remotebox
```

and attempt to start Chrome,

```
$ google-chrome
```

a local Chrome window opens, but it is just the window and the title bar.  No tabs, menu bar, bookmarks, etc.  Essentially a white window.  I can not use Firefox as my browser.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm aware of this post, https://askubuntu.com/questions/3515/how-do-i-launch-a-remote-firefox-window-via-ssh, but it did not help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I launch a remote firefox window via SSH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3515/how-do-i-launch-a-remote-firefox-window-via-ssh)

Comment: No, it does not.  I've already looked at that post.  It deals with Firefox, not Chrome.