# No new Firefox window open after start it via ssh -X on remote server

Tags: ssh, xorg, firefox

I can't open a remote Firefox window in my terminal([**Tilix**](https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/)) via `ssh -x`:

```
sshpass -f .ssh/passwd ssh -X root@*.*.*.*

(Remote) firefox --no-remote
```

I already read some question like [How do I launch a remote firefox window via SSH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3515/how-do-i-launch-a-remote-firefox-window-via-ssh), but all of them don't help solve my problem.

There aren't any extra error message or a Firefox window in terminal (just no response and **no new window open**).

```
Local System: Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 LTS

Remote server: Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

Remote Firefox Version: Mozilla Firefox 76.0b8
```

Does it mean Firefox are running correctly but my local display settings  have problem?

[image: Stuck here for very long time...]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed - already answered

Comment: @jet Thanks, That error message disappeared after I install these 2 packages, But it still can't display it correctly(I wait for 2 minutes to ensure it).